# HMS: failed to turnOnPush

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services

I tried to init the HMS push api on my HUAWEI device, but when i invoke the turnOnPush function it always return false to me.

```
DEVICE: HUAWEI mate 8 NXT AL10
OS: EMUI 4.1
DEVELOP TOOL: flutter app + flutter plugin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log shows that your current device does not support the display of notification messages.

[image]

Acorrding to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/restrictions-0000001050040064), **Notification message display control function**  need to meet the requirements of EMUI **5.1** and later version.